# How to Bind ComboBox Selected Item property in code behind of UserControl in a Windows 8.1 store app

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml, windows-phone-8

The below XAML binding works fine, but I can't get the binding to work when creating it in the code behind of the user control rather than in XMAL like below.

```
SelectedItem="{Binding ElementName=LabelledComboBoxControl, Path=SelectedItem, Mode=OneWay}"
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Hi - please put all code indented by 4 spaces - this highlights the code in a block. Hopefully someone will now be able to help. Welcome to SO

Comment: Do you have any good reason for trying to do that in code rather than XAML?

Comment: Yes, The scenario is slightly complicated to explain, so I won't. I expected it to be easy to replace the XAML binding with a code behind binding but nothing I have tried so far has worked.

Comment: Could you post what you have tried in the cod behind so far please?

Answer (score 0):

Well, the equivalent binding in code behind would be something like this:

```
element.SetBinding(Selector.SelectedItemProperty, new Binding() {
    Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedItem"),
    Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
    Source = this.LabelledComboBoxControl;
});
```

Here, `element` is the UI element whose SelectedItem property is binded in the code that you shared. I assume you have `this.LabelledComboBoxControl` which is the element that you're binding to. Also, you may change `Selector.SelectedItemProperty` to `ActualElementType.SelectedItemProperty` but I guess whatever you are using is just extending Selector, so it would be the same.